# How to add an IE field for my wifi hotspot?

Tags: wifi, wifi-hotspot, iwlwifi, wpa-cli, iw

Is it possible to attach a IE field to my wifi hotspot so that it appear in the `iwlist` output of other machine scanning it?

Example:

- I choose `1234567891011121314151617181920` to be the additional field for my wifi hotspot (MAC address `11:22:33:44:55:66`)
- Users scanning my wifi hotspot with command `iwlist wlan0 scan`, should give the output:

  ```
    wlan0  Scan completed :
     Cell 01 - Address: 11:22:33:44:55:66
    [...]
    IE: Unknown 1234567891011121314151617181920
    [...]
  ```

Comment: This would all depend on what wifi-hotspot you have, as it is this that is being configured. (This does not seem to be a Unix question. If it is then please clarify.)

Comment: What does your hotspot run on (software and what access do you have)? Unless you have full access because e.g. you set it up yourself I don't think this question belongs here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE stands for Information Element. They are transmitted as part of the beacon frames and carry all kinds of information such as SSID, supported rates, etc.

```
Information element                        Element ID    Length (in octets)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSID (see 7.3.2.1)                         0             2 to 34
Supported rates (see 7.3.2.2)              1             3 to 10
FH Parameter Set (see 7.3.2.3)             2             7
DS Parameter Set (see 7.3.2.4)             3             3
CF Parameter Set (see 7.3.2.5)             4             8
TIM (see 7.3.2.6)                          5             6 to 256
IBSS Parameter Set (see 7.3.2.7)           6             4
Country (see 7.3.2.9)                      7             8 to 256
Hopping Pattern Parameters (see 7.3.2.10)  8             4
Hopping Pattern Table (see 7.3.2.11)       9             6 to 256
Request (see 7.3.2.12)                     10            2 to 256
BSS Load (see 7.3.2.28)                    11            7
EDCA Parameter Set (see 7.3.2.29)          12            20
TSPEC (see 7.3.2.30)                       13            57
TCLAS (see 7.3.2.31)                       14            2 to 257
Schedule (see 7.3.2.34)                    15            16
Challenge text (see 7.3.2.8)               16            3 to 255
Reserved                                   17–31
Power Constraint (see 7.3.2.15)            32            3
Power Capability (see 7.3.2.16)            33            4
TPC Request (see 7.3.2.17)                 34            2
TPC Report (see 7.3.2.18)                  35            4
Supported Channels (see 7.3.2.19)          36            4 to 256
Channel Switch Announcement (see 7.3.2.20) 37            5
Measurement Request (see 7.3.2.21)         38            5 to 16
Measurement Report (see 7.3.2.22)          39            5 to 24
Quiet (see 7.3.2.23)                       40            8
IBSS DFS (see 7.3.2.24)                    41            10 to 255
ERP Information (see 7.3.2.13)             42            3
TS Delay (see 7.3.2.32)                    43            6
TCLAS Processing (see 7.3.2.33)            44            3
Reserved                                   45
QoS Capability (see 7.3.2.35)              46            3
Reserved                                   47
RSN (see 7.3.2.25)                         48            36 to 256
Reserved                                   49
Extended Supported Rates (see 7.3.2.14)    50            3 to 257
Reserved                                   51–126
Extended Capabilities                      127           2 to 257
Reserved                                   128–220
Vendor Specific (see 7.3.2.26)             221           3 to 257
Reserved                                   222–255
```

Some of these information elements are vendor specific, meaning they will probably be ignored by other vendors. Reserved means it may have a standard meaning in the future, in fact some of them already have. (I'm looking at an old standard.) You can configure them in [hostapd.conf](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf)

```
# Additional vendor specific elements for Beacon and Probe Response frames
# This parameter can be used to add additional vendor specific element(s) into
# the end of the Beacon and Probe Response frames. The format for these
# element(s) is a hexdump of the raw information elements (id+len+payload for
# one or more elements)
vendor_elements=dd0411223301
```

The hex data is the of the following structure:

[image: Vendor Specific Information Element Format]

The Element ID shall be dd, OUI is a 3-byte number allocated by [IEEE](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt), but the good news is iwlist displays all of them as unknown, except WPA (0050f2) and WPA2 (000fac).